# Passing arguments to a nested function in Python

Tags: python, nested, plotly

I have two functions, called `update_y_with_x` and `update_x`, which are as follows:

*update_y_with_x*

```
def update_y_with_x(chosen_tissue):
    for i, trace in enumerate(f.data):
        if trace.type == "scatter":
            # reset all line width
            f.data[i].line.width = 1

            if chosen_tissue in trace.text:
                f.data[i].line.width = 1 + 9
```

*update_x*

```
def update_x(trace, points, selector):
    if len(points.point_inds) == 0:
        return

    # Remove existing bar shades and linked lines' highlights
    f.layout.shapes = ()

    for i, trace in enumerate(f.data):
        if trace.type == "scatter" and f.data[i].line.width != 1:
            f.data[i].line.width = 1

    # Get tissue identity
    chosen_tissue = f.data[points.trace_index].y[points.point_inds[0]]

    # Get the index of the chosen tissue
    possible_trace_indices = [
        i for i, trace in enumerate(f.data) if trace.type == "bar"
    ]
    chosen_tissue_ranks = [
        list(f.data[index].y).index(chosen_tissue) for index in possible_trace_indices
    ]

    for i, _ in enumerate(possible_trace_indices):
        # Specify the y-range around the clicked bar for shading
        y0 = chosen_tissue_ranks[i] + 0.5
        y1 = y0 - 1

        f.add_hrect(
            y0=y0,
            y1=y1,
            line_width=0,
            fillcolor="grey",
            opacity=0.3,
            row=1,
            col=i * 2 + 1,
        )

    # Update lines
    update_y_with_x(chosen_tissue)
```

As you can see, update_x calls the update_y_with_x function, at the moment, both use a hard-coded plotly go figurewidget, where

`f = go.FigureWidget(fig)`

and are called like so:

```
for i, trace in enumerate(f.data):
    if trace.type == 'bar':  # Check if it's a barplot
        f.data[i].on_click(update_x)
```

I would like to do two things:

1. Move these two functions to an independent function file and import them into the main.ipynb file I'm working with
2. Pass `f`  as a parameter to each function, rather than having it hard - coded as it currently exists in the function, and make sure that it is passed to `update_y_with_x` prior to it being used in `update_x`

`update_x` click events on a bar plot. When a bar is clicked, it removes existing shapes, resets line widths for linked scatter plots, adds shaded rectangles around the clicked bars, and updates lines which link these bars together.

**What I tried:**

I initially exported these functions to a new file called "click_events.py", and added in the argument for each `figure_widget`, like so:

- def update_x(`trace, points, selector, figure_widget):` (replaced f in file)
- def update_y_with_x(`chosen_tissue, figure_widget):` (replaced f in file)
- modify the code in `update_x` so that `update_y_with_x(chosen_tissue, figure_widget = figure_widget)`

However, I believe that when I imported and try to run these functions in the way mentioned above the figure_widget isn't being passed to 'update_y_with_x'.

Comment: What is `update_x` and how does it call `update_y_with_x()`?

Comment: Really sorry, forgot to update the code to reflect the proper function names and a quick description of update_x!

Comment: How did you get on with your two objectives?

Comment: Just edited to reflect what I tried! Let me know if that's adequate :)

Comment: Python cares nothing for what you believe. What happened when you actually tried to run your code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For the two goals you mentioned, moving the functions to an independent file and passing `f` as a parameter

### Steps:

##### 1. Create an Independent Function File:

Create a new Python file (let's call it `plot_utils.py` for example) and move the functions `update_y_with_x` and `update_bar` into this file. The content of `plot_utils.py` would look like this:

```py
# plot_utils.py

import plotly.graph_objects as go

def update_y_with_x(fig, chosen_tissue):
    for i, trace in enumerate(fig.data):
        if trace.type == "scatter":
            # reset all line width
            fig.data[i].line.width = 1

            if chosen_tissue in trace.text:
                fig.data[i].line.width = 1 + 9

def update_bar(fig, trace, points, selector):
    if len(points.point_inds) == 0:
        return

    # Remove existing bar shades and linked lines' highlights
    fig.layout.shapes = ()

    for i, trace in enumerate(fig.data):
        if trace.type == "scatter" and fig.data[i].line.width != 1:
            fig.data[i].line.width = 1

    # Get tissue identity
    chosen_tissue = fig.data[points.trace_index].y[points.point_inds[0]]

    # Get the index of the chosen tissue
    possible_trace_indices = [
        i for i, trace in enumerate(fig.data) if trace.type == "bar"
    ]
    chosen_tissue_ranks = [
        list(fig.data[index].y).index(chosen_tissue) for index in possible_trace_indices
    ]

    for i, _ in enumerate(possible_trace_indices):
        # Specify the y-range around the clicked bar for shading
        y0 = chosen_tissue_ranks[i] + 0.5
        y1 = y0 - 1

        fig.add_hrect(
            y0=y0,
            y1=y1,
            line_width=0,
            fillcolor="grey",
            opacity=0.3,
            row=1,
            col=i * 2 + 1,
        )

    # Update lines
    update_y_with_x(fig, chosen_tissue)
```

##### 2. In your Main Jupyter Notebook (`main.ipynb`):

In your main Jupyter Notebook, you can import these functions and use them as follows:

```py
# main.ipynb

import plot_utils
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# Create the initial figure
f = go.FigureWidget(fig)

# Register the on_click event
for i, trace in enumerate(f.data):
    if trace.type == 'bar':  # Check if it's a barplot
        f.data[i].on_click(lambda trace, points, selector: plot_utils.update_bar(f, trace, points, selector))
```

Now, both `update_y_with_x` and `update_bar` are in a separate file, and you can import and use them in your main notebook. The `f` figure is passed as a parameter to both functions, making them more flexible and avoiding hard coding.

Comment: Please note that use of AI Tools (e.g., ChatGPT) to generate or reword content that you post [is not permitted](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831) on Stack Overflow, even if you vet this content beforehand. Also see the related [Help](/help/ai-policy) on this topic. We do hope you'll stick around and continue to be a valuable member of the community by contributing your own quality answers and questions in the future!

Comment: @ParvathirajanNatarajan The problem is that [it is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned). To quote that ban notice, "This includes 'asking' the question to an AI generator then copy-pasting its output _as well as_ using an AI generator to 'reword' your answers."

Comment: @ParvathirajanNatarajan While [I'm personally hopeful](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/426942/11810933) that one day we'll be able to allow some form of this, there are several problems today - First, ChatGPT (and others) have a tendency to insert their own "concepts" into reworded answers.  Second, we just have too many people using it irresponsibly still.

Comment: so everyone should write their answer in complete lower case and without proper punctuation and a formatting to prove that they're not ai . it is amazing. thanks for the responses . i have gained these reputation without any ai so far. - note : this comment is not by my chat gpt . - by me